# How to get the background of a UIListView to extend to the edges of the screen in landscape?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can I get the background of a UIListView in a UIViewControllerRepresentable to extend to the edges of the screen in landscape? Ideally the scrollbar should be outside of the safe area as is typical. Here is a full non-working example and a screenshot. Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Foundation

@main
struct TestLSTableApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ListContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ListContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ListControllerRepresentable()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
}

struct ListControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: ListControllerRepresentable.Context) -> ListController {
        ListController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ListController, context: Context) {}
}

class ListController: UITableViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(style: .insetGrouped)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        //tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false // this doesn't help
        //tableView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth // this doesn't help
        //tableView.layoutIfNeeded() // this doesn't help
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
         return "Section"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `.ignoresSafeArea()`? Are you not aware of this view modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your code, added a `.ignoreSafeArea` view modifier and added a red border.

`.ignoresSafeArea(.container)` lets the ListView expand beyond the safe areas, so the entire screen has the same grey background. There are more options for the `.ignoreSafeArea` [1]

You'll see that the List view is filling the entire screen but the contents are included within the red border.

```
struct ListContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ListControllerRepresentable()
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
                .border(.red)
        }
      
    }
}
```

[image]

[1] Apple documentation `SafeAreaRegions` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/safearearegions